# How can I verbosely track the whole process of calling a function?

Tags: c++, dll, call, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I'm currently developing a tool that need to call a non-imported function of a DLL (let us call it `Third.DLL` and the function `func(arg)`. `func` create a stack variable `Type var` and passed it to `func_impl(arg)`. So in order to use it directly, I implemented my own `func_mine(arg)`, found the offset address for `Type::Type()` and `func_impl(arg)`, and then wrote

```cpp
int func_mine(arg...) // arg... just as a placeholder here, not real C++ code
{
    auto con = DLL_Base_Add + GetOffset("Type::Type()");
    Type* type = (Type* )new char[sizeof(Type)];
    con(type);

    auto impl = DLL_Base_Add + GetOffset("func_impl(...)");
    return impl(arg...);
}
```

The function terminates normally, and in those `arg...`, one is returned back, but I found the returned variables are not identical, I tried

1. call `func` directly
2. call `func` directly
3. call `func` directly
4. call `func_mine`
5. call `func_mine`
6. call `func` directly
7. call `func` directly

I notices that 1,2,3 produced result 1 while 4,5,6,7 produced result 2. I cannot understand this behaviour, something's modified and cannot be recovered after calling `func_mine`. And I want result 1 instead of 2.

What may be the reasons of this phenomenon? how can I find which variable's incorrectly modified? Is there any tool I can use to verbosely track and dump the data section and stack space for each assembly instruction? It will cost me a lot of time to MANUALLY check all the variables for all stack frames, and after every instructions.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not legal in C++ and depends on the implementation you are using and the **exact** details of your code. Every single little thing matters, so please no vague pseudocode. Post a [mre].

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI What I'm asking for are just guesses, methods and tools, and since I can debug myself, the codes really doesn't matter. And of course, it's long and linked to a private dll as well, there's no possibility to publish the codes and produce minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Well the tool is any debugger worth its money (such as gdb). Script it to produce a dump a stepi instruction, and tun in a loop.